# Can Javascript transact with a SQLite database on a remote server from a browser?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I would like to interact (select, insert, update, delete) with a SQLite database that is on my server using Javascript running on a remote browser.

Comment: You could use AJAX to communicate with a backend that could then interact with a database.

Answer (score 2):

No. Not directly.

The remote server would need to expose a "Web API" - which could be used/consumed by the browser JavaScript - that is *run on the system with direct access* to the SQLite database.

There [*are* some existing proxies](https://github.com/shepsii/SQLite-Proxy-ST2) that "allow direct data access" - you'll need to find or craft a suitable tool. I recommend writing a Web API that *doesn't* expose SQL directly, but rather exposes the required operations independent of the actual back-end.

Comment: I am trying to do the same but my HTML is in SCORM package and I want to collect some interaction details from learners. As my main intention is to do everything within a package which will on server but we can not use any server side script like PHP, JSP and ASP. Is it possible to do this with server side JavaScript if so then please provide some help links.